# Typescript, ES6, Angular 12: map/copy similar object

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have two model objects which are very similar (Angular 12 frontend):

```
export interface UserGet {
   id: string;
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   hobby: Hobby;
}

export interface UserPost {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   hobby: number;
}

export interface Hobby {
   id: string;
   hobby: string;
}
```

I want to map the a UserGet-object to a UserPost-object.

Current approach with a given userGet-object:

```
const userPost: userPost = {
   firstName: this.userGet.firstName,
   lastName: this.userGet.lastName,
   hobby: this.userGet.hobby.id;
 }
```

Looks simple, however in reality, I have a lot of more fields and I need to map alot of more objects in the same approach.

Is there a shorter/more elegant ES6 typescript solution to map models which, similar to my example, have the following structure:

- some fields might be missing in the target object
- some fields might be of different type in the target object

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, you are looking for like a `Automapper` but for  javascript/typescript?

Comment: why would you want this? why not just have 1 object for both if the contract is the same? it makes no sense having 2 contracts based on the http operation, specifically if you're modifying the same resource.

Comment: @Bargros: model design is exactly what I have asked in my other thread. I heared the GET field types must not be exactly the same like the POST only because it's the same entity. Hence the contract is not the same. Please comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67940442 if you have another opinion on this

Comment: I have replied in your other thread.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having strictly what is necessary in your model.

If you say you have a LOT more of propperties to match:

- Are those properties strictly needed to be handle in your frontend
  app?
- Does your frontend app really need all those properties?
- Is your backend responding with lots of unnecessary properties?

```js
export interface UserSomething {
  id?: string;  // id can be optional ( ? )
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  hobby: Hobby | number | string;
}
```

You can have a single model that holds all those properties, some can be optional, others, required.

When matching, you can try something like this:

```js
const user: UserSomething = {
  firstName: this.userGet.firstname; 
  lastName: this.userGet.lastName;
  hobby: this.userGet?.hobby; // it allows number, string or Hobby type of data
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I had this model design in mind, however it was proposed against when I asked for opinions (see stackoverflow.com/questions/67940442). Please comment there if you think this is the way to go over separate models for each http request type.